# $(window).scrollTop() returns 0 when used with material.min.css

Tags: jquery, html, css, material-design

I have been trying to use `$(window).scroll()` function. So if i remove material.min.css it works fine, but once i include this file it returns 0. Following is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var eTop = $('.wrapper1').offset().top; //this gives correct value
    console.log(eTop - $(window).scrollTop()); //this returns 0 when used with mdl css

    $(window).scroll(function() { //when window is scrolled
        console.log($(window).scrollTop());
    });
});
```

Comment: Perhaps a JSFiddle with your problem would be a good thing to add, so we can replicate what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

You can reference the `<main>` element instead of the window, e.g.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0].scrollTop
```

Or, since you appear to have jQuery as well,

```
$('main').scrollTop()
```

(This approach assumes you're using one of the mdl templates that relies on the `<main>` element or something equivalent.)